# gitlab error - the remote en hung up unexpectedly

Tags: gitlab

I installed Gitlab on my Ubuntu successfully(gitlab.domain.com), on a client PC I installed Git (windows 7), then run Git Bash to generate SSH keys with command: ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "username@domain.com" to create private/public keys on C:\Users\AccountName.ssh
Then, add public key to profile on installed gitlab. Then can clone/push on Git Bash.

However, I can not reproduce this on other PCs, I tried some PCs, created new users, new ssh keys...
but always encounter that error "The remote end hung up unexpectedly", sometimes can clone but also get that error when pushing.

I can only clone/push on first PC. I'm so confused, don't know what I missed. I'm trying to get my team on Git

Thanks a lot for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are pointing it at the correct git server. Also - login on your Jenkins server (Under the jenkins user) and ssh to git@your-git-server and make sure to select 'yes' to add the server to your known hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was an access-level problem :

my user only had guest access to my project so it wasn't able to clone it. I changed the access level to developper and it solved my problem